# Select divs of invisible area in browser

Tags: jquery

I have a web page with 5000px in height and it contains multiple divs with same class. On page load, in my browser I can see only the following red marked portion without scrolling.

[image]

How can I select and apply a class to the divs of non red area using jquery.

Comment: what do you mean by "target"?

Comment: @Joshan: Edited my question, re-consider the -1

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, like that?

```
$('.myDiv');
```

jQuery search through entire DOM, it don't cares how big your screensize is.

Comment: Yes you're correct, but I need to select and apply a class on that non red area items

Answer (score 0):

jQuery "selects" elements in the entire DOM (HTML), regardless of whether it is in the scroll / visible area or not. So using a selection like:

`$('#myDiv').doSomeJqueryMagic()`

... works as expected.